# Catching a Promise exception and returning a default value

Tags: ember.js, rsvp.js

I am having an issue where I want to return a default value if an exception occurs on a promise.  The array I return does not seem to work properly.

My Route model hook

```
model: function() {
    return {
        menuItems : this.store.find('menuItem').catch(function(error) {
            Ember.Logger.error('Retrieving Menu Items', error);
            return [];
        }),
```

My controller mode

```
selectFirstMenuItem: function() {
    var model = this.get('model');

    //At this point model.menuItems is some weird object 
    //with an _id : 26, _label : undefined, _result: Array(0), _state : 1 etc. 
    //(maybe a Promise?),  the .get method throws an undefined exception.
    if(model.menuItems.get('length') > 0 ) {
        ...
    }
}.observes('model.menuItems.@each'),
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe the rejection then is fired in this case (...then(func(){}, func(){.. rejected ...})?

Comment: @EntspAndi I don't follow.  Are you suggesting a .then() after the .catch()?

Comment: @EntspAndi I think I know what you mean now.  .then() accepts two functions, success and failure.  I tried that but got the same result. when returning from the failure hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this work by returning an [`Ember.RSVP.hash`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/RSVP.html#method_hash) instead of a regular object containing a promise as follows:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {    
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      menuItems: this.store.find('menuItem').then(
        function(menuItems){ return menuItems; },
        function(error) {
          Ember.Logger.error('Retrieving Menu Items', error);
          return [];
        })
    });
  }
});
```

And then watching for the `length` property of `menuItems` as follows:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  menuItemsObserver: function() {
    var menuItems = this.get('model.menuItems');

    var nonZeroLength = Ember.get(menuItems, 'length');
    if(nonZeroLength ) {
      console.log("The length is NOT zero");
    }
    else {
      console.log("The length is zero");
    }
  }.observes('model.menuItems.length')  
});
```

Working example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sujaso/3/edit?html,js,console)